# Laravel facebook Oauth

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, laravel-4

I am using [CodeSleeve/social](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/stapler) in laravel for Facebook authorization and authentication. How to make it return username? I can see email, link etc.

my controller is:

> ```
> public function facebook() {
>
>
>     if (! Social::check('facebook')) {
>         return Redirect::to('login');
>     }
>     else {
>         $user = Social::facebook('/me');
>         dd($user);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

What should I do next to get the username? I'm new into this oauth.

Comment: In Facebook API v2.0 you can't get username

Comment: is there a way to generate the same username that facebook uses in my application?

Comment: Ask the user for it and hope they fill in the same. Facebook will not give it to you